# UITableView Scrolls To Undesired Index or Position

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, scroll, scrollview

Basically the task is to load new API response as the user scrolls to down in `UITableView` without stopping user interaction and maintaining the current position (live feeds like Facebook and Instagram).

What I want to do is that parsing and then viewing Rest API's response in `UITableView` with custom cells.

The issue is that when the user scrolls to bottom the API call is made and table view scrolls to some other position where the user is.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count;
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xxxxx", for:indexPath) as! xxxxxxxx

    return cell;
}



func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if scrollView == tableView {
        if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
            print("Scroll Ended")
            fetchDataFromApi()
        }
    }
}


func fetchDataFromApi() {

    let jsonUrlString = "xxxxxxx"


    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        return
    }

    print(url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,err) in

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do {
            let apiResponseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiResponse.self, from: data)

            if apiResponseData.httpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK {

                if let apiResponse = apiResponseData.data{
                    self.array.append(contentsOf: apiResponse)
                }


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            }
            else {
                print("API Response Error : \(apiResponseData.httpStatusCode) \(apiResponseData.errorMessage)")
            }
        }catch let jsonErr {
            print("Serialization Error \(jsonErr)")
        }
        }.resume()
}}
```

Comment: I don't see any mistake in code make sure your `fetchDataFromApi` gets called only once, scrollViewDelegate gets called multiple times so may be your fetchDataFromApi gets called multiple times resulting in reloadData being triggered multiple times. One simple tweak u can do is add a bool variable to check if request is in progress and if yes return without actually making API call

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari can u suggest where I can place flag I had tried but it didn't work for me

Comment: Try having a instance variable in your TableView Controller initialize it with default value of false and in fetchDataFromApi set it to true finally once I receive the data before calling reloadData set it to false again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of dynamic cell sizes I was setting in table view

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xxxxx", for:indexPath) as! xxxxxxxx

    let lastRowIndex = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: tableView.numberOfSections-1)

    if (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex - 1) {
         //print("last row selected")
        fetchDataFromApi()
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If you are using this so no need to call this method

> scrollViewDidEndDragging

Answer (score 0):

try `insertCellAtIndexPath` replace for `tableview.reloadData()` in

```
if let apiResponse = apiResponseData.data{
                self.array.append(contentsOf: apiResponse)
            }


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

......

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this. The most favourable as far as I see it is to implement a paginated API and call the API once the UITableView's last item. You may use:

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
let botEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;

if (botEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
{
// Call API and reload TableView on completion handler.
}
}
```

Call the tableView reload on the completion handler of the API method.

Or you can do it in a slightly more awkward way:

```
public var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get }
```

Get the array of index paths of the currently visible cells and scroll to the index after you reload the UITableView using:

```
tableView.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: false)
```